# Putting instantiated objects in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

1. Below is all the code for the program I am writing for my programming class. My main problem is that when I invoke AddPerson() it skips the position [0] in _people[] and places the object created in [1] of _More[]. How can i prevent this from happening while also adding newly created objects to the array?
2. Also, i need to at the end display all of the data in the array in ordered form. I believe I have the proper code in the DisplayAllPeople() method in the GroupOfPeople class.

I'm hoping I have most of this correct. Can anyone help me please?

*There is one class called IOHelper that was provided to us (the students) by our teacher but I did not include it as it is only static methods.

//Main Program//

public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GroupOfPeople group = new GroupOfPeople();

```
        while (IOHelper.AskYesNoQuestion("Do you want to add another person to the array? "))
        {
            Console.Write("Name?   :");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Age?    :");
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Person newPerson = new Person(name, age);

            group.AddPerson(newPerson);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Here are your entries:");

        group.DisplayAllPeople();

        Console.Write("Press any key to end the program... ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

 }
```

//Person Class//

public class Person
    {
        private string _name { get; set; }
        private int _age { get; set; }

```
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
    }


    public void Display()
    {
        Console.Write("Name : " + _name);
        Console.Write("Age  : " + _age);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

//GroupOfPeople Class//

public class GroupOfPeople
    {
        private Person[] _people;

```
    public GroupOfPeople()
    {
        _people = new Person[0];
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person newPerson)
    {

        Person[] _More= new Person[_people.Length +1];
        _More[_people.Length] = newPerson;
        _people = _More;

    }



    public void DisplayAllPeople()
    {
        foreach (Person newPerson in _people)
        {
            newPerson.Display();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have this coded right now, each time you add a person you are creating a new array and only saving the last added person:

```
   Person[] _More= new Person[_people.Length +1];
   _More[_people.Length] = newPerson;
   _people = _More;
```

If you want to re-size the array each time you add an entry to it, you should copy the already existing elements to the newly created array.

Also, if you're re-sizing the array, a better approach is to pre-alocate more space than you need and each time increase the size by a certain amount, proportional to the current size of the array (this could be 1/2 of the array size, of 3/4, or some other proprotion). This way you're not incurring the cost of resizing (copying the previous elements of the array) each time you add an element.

Or you could use a generic `List<Person>` which uses an array backing store, if your programming assignment will allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy references from old to new array:

```
public void AddPerson(Person newPerson)
{
    Person[] _More= new Person[_people.Length +1];
    Array.Copy(_people, _More, _people.Length);
    _More[_people.Length] = newPerson;
    _people = _More;

}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I actually had that in there before, and when I was trying to make it all work i accidentally took it out and forgot to put it back in. Thanks for the help!!